# Regular Expression to grab id from selectors?

Tags: css, regex

I am attempting to extract a element's id from a selector. For example if I have the following selector `body .foo #bar` I wish to extract the `#bar` text. And for `#foo:hover` I wish to extract `#foo`. I have created a regular expression that works for all cases except for selectors that contain `:`, so it doesn't work for my last example `#foo:hover`. It seems to be greedy and grabs all text `#foo:hover` instead of just `#foo`

See here for an example of my issue: https://regex101.com/r/7Rk6AL/2

Can you suggest how I edit my regex to achieve my goal of just getting the selector id and not the `:hover` part?

Comment: Without `#foo`, it's just `:hover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ID must begin with a letter and may be followed by any number of letters, digits, hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")

Because you do not want things like ::after and :hover, this will work as well

```
#[a-zA-Z0-9|\-|_|\.]+
```

Comment: Please note that the regex is also true if the first character of the id is not a letter. This is done to handle some `<form>` generators who do not follow the w3c rules. The id's accepted by the regex are also accepted by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is due of you using the `.*` selector for your id. it won't just stop at the colon. What you could do is replace this selector with a more specific one (`[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]`, [ref](http://xahlee.info/js/html_allowed_chars_in_attribute.html)).

```
(#[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]*)(?:[:|\s]{1})
```

You can use [this regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yWL4dB/2) to test more cases.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this works, if anyone knows a better solution please let me know:

> /(#.*?)(:|\s)/gmi

https://regex101.com/r/7Rk6AL/3

Comment: the accepted answer isn't 100% correct. We can start ID's with intergers: https://jsfiddle.net/bvge2uwd/1/ .. related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6732899/8620333